# Path of a process defined via Lebesgue integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Consider the following equation: 
$$ X_t = 1 + \int_0^t a(u) du$$
where $a(\cdot) : [0,\infty) \to [-1,1]$ is a measurable function and the integral is a Lebesgue integral.

Suppose $a(u) = -1$ for all $u \le 1$. Hence, $X_1 = 0$.

Suppose I want the process to remain at $0$ forever. One way I could achieve this is by setting $a(u) = 0$ for all $u > 1$. Alternatively, I would like to say that the following function should also keep the process at $0$ forever.

\begin{align*}
a(u) = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{ if } X_u > 0\\
1 & \text{ if } X_u \leq 0 \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Intuitively, the reason is that by setting $a_u = -1$ whenever $X_u > 0$ I am decreasing $X$. Since I start at $1$, I will hit $0$. Once I am at $0$, I reverse the direction of movement, but only for an instant and the process is pushed back to $0$.

But I have no idea if this is correct. If yes, what is the formal way to argue this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. Indeed we can easily see that this doesn't work because you want $X_t=0$ for all $t\geq 1$. But then we get $a(u) =1$ for all $u\geq 1$. These two things can never happen at the same time..

Comment: Thanks. This sounds right. But then, I would flip the question around and ask, what does the process I describe do, if it is well-defined?

Comment: @avk255 yeah I don't know, but I don't think that it would be well-defined. Good question tho